# EF SaveChanges not saving and not throwing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a method that creates a new user and then insert a row in the User Permission table, but nothing is happening. Here is my code:

```
// before: creates user

var permission = new UserPermission()
{
    UserId = user.Id,
    UserName = user.UserName,
    Assets = createUserModel.Assets
};

AccountDb.UserPermissions.Add(permission);
var saveChangesResult = AccountDb.SaveChanges();

if (saveChangesResult == 0) // the result is always 0
{
    AppUserManager.Delete(user);
    return BadRequest("User permission could not be saved");
}

// then: add user to role and return ok
```

SaveChanges always returns 0 and doesn't update the database, I've already googled for it and tried the following actions:

```
// no success
AccountDb.UserPermissions.Attach(permission);

// no success either
AccountDb.Entry(permission).State = EntityState.Added;
```

And I tried in async method too, but no luck.
Here is my "UserPermission" model:

```
public class UserPermission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string _Assets { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<int> Assets
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Assets == null) return null;
            return Array.ConvertAll(_Assets.Split(';'), Int32.Parse).ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            _Assets = String.Join(";", value.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

It's curious because this method was working lately, but after some changes in "AccountContext" and some rolebacks, I notice that the method wasn't working anymore.

-- edit --

here is the full create method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("create")]
public IHttpActionResult CreateUser(CreateUserBindingModel createUserModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (createUserModel.RoleName is null)
    {
        return BadRequest("There is no role assigned to user");
    }

    var user = new UserModel()
    {
        UserName = createUserModel.UserName,
        Email = createUserModel.Email,
        FirstName = createUserModel.FirstName,
        LastName = createUserModel.LastName
    };

    var addUserResult = AppUserManager.Create(user, createUserModel.Password);

    if (!addUserResult.Succeeded)
    {
        return GetErrorResult(addUserResult);
    }

    var permission = new UserPermission()
    {
        UserId = user.Id,
        UserName = user.UserName,
        Assets = createUserModel.Assets
    };

    AccountDb.UserPermissions.Add(permission);
    var saveChangesResult = AccountDb.SaveChanges();

    if (saveChangesResult == 0)
    {
        AppUserManager.Delete(user);
        return BadRequest("User permission could not be saved");
    }

    var addRoleResult = AppUserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, createUserModel.RoleName);

    if (!addRoleResult.Succeeded)
    {
        AppUserManager.Delete(user);
        return GetErrorResult(addUserResult);
    }

    return Ok(TheModelFactory.Create(user));
}
```

-- edit 2 --

I was using an Azure db string and I changed to a local db string, but the problem still is the same, UserPermissions Table does not update and no error is emiting.

Comment: It's probably updating the wrong database.

Comment: Are you sure you are targetting the right connection string? What happens if you add `AccountDb.Database.Log += Console.WriteLine;` before the save, do you get any SQL executed? If so, what SQL?

Comment: You don't have a transaction somewhere lurking about?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft If its updating the wrong database, woudn't SaveChanges still return 1 ?

Comment: Can You add Create User code?
Create user uses the same context  in create user and add permission?

Comment: And if its different db context for create user, and create permission, are they targeting the same DB? Or the same connection string?

Comment: The db string is correct. By the way, if you get all user permissions with: "AccountDb.UserPermissions.ToList()", it returns the same as in the database table

Comment: @Eduardo Rosostolato good point.  Can you create a repro (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @DavidG How do I use `AccountDb.Database.Log` with `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`?

Comment: Same way I showed you above.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I can't do it right now but I try later. My code has some copyright so I can't share everything. Thanks for helping

Comment: @DavidG it says: `Cannot create delegate with 'Debug.WriteLine(string)' because it or a method it overrides has a Conditional attribute`

Comment: Then try `AccountDb.Database.Log += s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);`

Comment: Nothing happened, I did `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----------testing-------------"); AccountDb.Database.Log += s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);` and only "testing" was written to the console

Comment: Not exactly sure about EF, but a lot of ORMs like that get really finicky if your table doesn't have a primary key that the ORM knows about.  Does your table have a PK and is that mapped appropriately for EF?

Comment: PK was not the problem, I found the solution and the problem is the local db context, somehow it was not working, but when I created a new instace all went out. Thanks all for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution!

For some reason, my local instance of AccountContext was the problem, it gets all UserPermissions but doesn't update. So I created a new instance and tried to add the permission:

```
using (var db = new AccountContext())
{
     db.UserPermissions.Add(permission);
     var saveChangesResult = db.SaveChanges();

     if (saveChangesResult == 0)
     {
         AppUserManager.Delete(user);
         return BadRequest("User permission could not be saved");
     }
}
```

now it's working well. But I don't know why the local AccountDb is not working now if it was working in the past

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new user, but you never use the result. Your `user.Id` is *always* null (or the respective default).

I don't know why your database fails silently (constraints or foreign keys should throw an exception), but you should fix that first. It will probably result in real records being written.

Comment: User creating is working normally and it's generating an ID: https://i.imgur.com/CMXHrFK.jpg

Comment: @EduardoRosostolato Oh, you are modifying your input parameters? ok... that's weird but I guess within the language possibilities to do so.

Comment: Wich input parameters?

Comment: Your Create method writes to the user it gets. That was unexpected for me.

Comment: You're talking about the `return Ok(TheModelFactory.Create(user));`?

Comment: No, about `AppUserManager.Create`, that's the one that sets user.Id, right?

Comment: I did it just like this tutorial: http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/